# ERROR 1064 (42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: mysql, mariadb

el error me aparece así, mi profesor envió un video explicando creando las tablas, lo hice a base sus explicaciones, pero a mí me aparece ese error y cuando coloco el auto_increment también me sale erróneo
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 19: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(id_desarrollador) REFERENCES desarrollador(id)

```
CREATE DATABASE ventadevideojuegos;
USE ventadevideojuegos;

CREATE TABLE plataforma(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nombre CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE genero(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nombre CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE desarrollador(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nombre CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE juego(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    año INT NOT NULL,
    precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    publicador CHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    nombre CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    usuarios INT NOT NULL,
    valoracion INT NOT NULL,
    id_desarrollador INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN (id_desarrollador) REFERENCES desarrollador(id)
);
CREATE TABLE plataformajuego(
    id_plataforma INT NOT NULL,
    id_juego INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN (id_plataforma) REFERENCES plataforma(id),
    FOREIGN (id_juego) REFERENCES juego(id)
);
CREATE TABLE generojuego(
    id_genero INT NOT NULL,
    id_juego INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN (id_genero) REFERENCES genero(id),
    FOREIGN (id_juego) REFERENCES juego(id)
);
```

Comment: ¿Tenés la certeza de que es `FOREIGN` nada más? ;)